# How to pass multiple ids in API Get method Endpoint using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to pass multiple IDs in the GET Endpoint.
For example: If my database contains details of 10 employees with ID as primary key, and suppose i want to pass more than one id in the Endpoint at a particular point. Is this possible.
Suppose:

```
    http://localhost:8080/api/v/listempoloyee/{1,2,3,4}
```

{1,2,3,4} being the list of IDs of employess which we want to fetch from  Database.

Is this possible using Spring Boot and JDBC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609414/spring-mvc-passing-arraylist-back-to-controller  may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your request should be like this

```
 localhost:9363/products/1,2,...
```

dont add any kind of brackets, then in your controller class you can create an API like below

```
@GetMapping("/products/{Ids}")
public List<Product> getProducts(@PathVariable List<Long> Ids) 
{
    return this.service.getProducts(Ids);   // calling the service class as per 
                                                   the architecture
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
  @GetMapping("/{employeeIds}")
  public void trigger(@PathVariable String employeeIds) {
        List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(employeeIds.split(","));
        ..........
  }
```

now you have a list of ids in ***ids*** field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how will I pass the ids in the SQL query. I mean for a single employee details, i am simply triggering "jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM device_registration  WHERE Id= ?", new DeviceRowMapper(),id);""  But for passing multiple ids, I have to change the query too. Also How will i pass the id in endpoint. I mean "/employeeList/{1,2,3}".

Answer (score -1):

```
                    you can send a post request to your controller.please follow these steps-:

                    1. **I need to  create a html file because of ajax calling.**
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <title>Ajax Test</title>
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="/js/ajaxCall.js"></script>
                        </head>

                        <body>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-update btn-primary" id="send">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Send Parameter
                            </button>
                        </body>
                    </html>

                2. **create a js file and create a function for ajax calling.**
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#send").on("click",function(){
                        var paramIds = ["1", "2", "3", "4","5"];
                        var parameterData = JSON.stringify({
                            'paramList' :paramIds
                        });
                        $.ajax({
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            method:'post',
                            data: parameterData,
                            url: "http://localhost:8080/get",
                            dataType: 'json',
                        }).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr, options) {

                        }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }).always(function(xhr, textStatus) {
                        });
                    })  

                });
            please focus on **JSON.stringify**.JSON.stringify convert javascript object to a string following the JSON notation.
        3. **create a form to accept paramter as a post request.**
        package com.example.demo;

        import java.util.List;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import lombok.Data;

        @Data
        public class ParameterForm {
        List<String> paramList=new ArrayList<>();
        }

            4. **create a controller class for accepting the post request.**
            package com.example.demo;

            import java.util.List;

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

            @Controller
            public class TestController {
            @RequestMapping(value="/home")
            public String checkParam()
            {
            return "test";  
            }
            @RequestMapping(value="/get",method = RequestMethod.POST)
            @ResponseBody
            public String getId(@RequestBody ParameterForm parameterForm)
            {
                List<String> paramList=parameterForm.getParamList();
                for(String param:paramList)
                {
                    System.out.println(param);
                }
                return "success";
            }
            }
    please focus on getId controller.
    you will find **@RequestBody ParameterForm parameterForm**.This form will accept the parameter which i send in ajax call. 

******************output**********************
1
2
3
4
5
```